# Showing error-no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle8i

I am using jdk1.8 and I am trying to execute a jdbc program manually on oracle 8i. My code is compiling without any error but at the run time its showing error-`no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl`. I have already set the class path for jar file. I am using `ojdbc7.jar` file.
My code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

class Database
{
 public static void main(String arg[])
    {

     try
       {
String url="jdbc:orcl:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";   
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"scott","tiger");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from aj1");

while(rs.next())
     {
    System.out.println("\n"+rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));
      }
    }
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

Kindly give the solution for this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You url String must be

String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

instead of

String url="jdbc:orcl:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

and try.